# Prometheus excessive requests using servive discovery

Tags: prometheus

I'm using service discovery for my servers hosted on Digital Ocean. I often hit a Digital Ocean rate limit when running Prometheus because it seems like Prometheus will call the API for each job. It there a way to tell it to just call out to Digital Ocean once and use that result for all jobs?

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'a1-nodes'
    digitalocean_sd_configs:
      - bearer_token: 'MY_TOKEN'
        port: 26661
      - bearer_token: 'MY_TOKEN'
        port: 9090
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_tags]
        regex: .*,prometheus,.*
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_tags]
        regex: .*,a1_node,.*
        action: keep        
  - job_name: 'a2-nodes'
    digitalocean_sd_configs:
      - bearer_token: 'MY_TOKEN'
        port: 26661
      - bearer_token: 'MY_TOKEN'
        port: 9090
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_tags]
        regex: .*,prometheus,.*
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_digitalocean_tags]
        regex: .*,a2_node,.*
        action: keep
```

Comment: Could you not just combine your 2 jobs into one with `regex: .*,a[12]_node,.*`? Even if you kept these as separate relabels but put them under a single job, you'd halve the number of calls. IIUC, that's the only way you can reduce the calls.

Comment: @DazWilkin That would have no effect, Prometheus already does that under the covers. Though that is often a good idea from a general config cleanliness standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers Prometheus will combine SD configs if they're exactly identical, so here you've two SD configs due to the different ports. To reduce it down to one you'd need to split things into four jobs, and add the port number in relabelling.

There's also a `refresh_interval` setting.